# Snatch at the death meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

From [the sport article](https://www.rt.com/sport/350586-portugal-wins-euro-2016-after/).

> But they struggled to find a way through the resolute Portugal
>   backline, however, and it was not until the final quarter of the match
>   did the game really spring into life, with both sides almost **snatching**
>   **the game at the death**.

I found that snatch means to try to take hold of something. But it sounds terrible in the context. What might snatch at the death stand for?

Comment: They likely mean winning the game with a goal very near the end, but it's not a phrase I've ever heard in English-language sports coverage. Not that I'm a huge soccer fan.

Comment: "Snatched at the death" is an idiom specific to football (what USAians call "soccer,") rugby, and Aussie rules. 
Among English speaking nations, it appears to be unknown or obscure **only** in the United States.

Answer (score 1):

**At the death** means *at the end of the game*.There are lots of such examples on the net.

> Bulls snatch it at the death.
>   With such a pulsating **end to the game** it was hard to remember that this is simply a pre-season outing, and not a game that means anything in the larger scheme of things.

It's a literary device called a metaphor, or a specific idiom used to make a sentence more expressive. As it was mentioned in the comment you shouldn't use it in speech in the USA

Comment: You should probably mention what English varieties use this phrase. Your example seems to be from Africa. OP's is from Russia. I think you might be understood but you'd at least get weird looks if you used this phrase when speaking to an American.